# Can't delete a file in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, chmod, unlink

I can't delete a file using `unlink()` and when I use `fopen` with the `"w"` tag, I get an error. The file has `777` chmod. I can use `fopen()` to write at the end of the file. But I can't delete anything.
Can anybody help me please?

Here's a sample:

```
   echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('..')), -4); //777
   echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('.')), -4); //777
   echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('test')), -4); //777
   chmod('tmp',0777);  //Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

To `unlink` a file, you need write permission on the directory it's in. Having the file itself `chmod`'d `777` won't help

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue before and been able to remedy by forcing garbage collection after closing the file and before unlinking it:

```
gc_collect_cycles();
```

By far not the best solution, but it did resolve an issue I had deleting files that had been previously opened and closed lines before.